# How to improve this list comprehension, need to return Nth Even Number, do I need a list or dict of even numbers?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Return the Nth Even Number (imagine a list of even numbers, return the number at human eye position of input number)

Example(Input --> Output)

```
1 --> 0 (the first even number is 0)

3 --> 4 (the 3rd even number is 4 (0, 2, 4))
```

#### Test:

```
(nth_even(3), --> 4)
(nth_even(1), --> 0)
(nth_even(2), --> 2)
(nth_even(100), --> 198)
(nth_even(1298734), --> 2597466)
```

#### My code:

My code times out when dealing with the larger numbers so I need a quicker way.

```
def nth_even(n):
data = [num for num in range(0, n*2) if num % 2 == 0]
return data[n-1]
```

Comment: You definitely don't need a list comprehension =)  Notice how you don't refer to any element but the last

Comment: Another pyrrhic victory for comprehensions. Well done. I’m upvoting both the clever/sensible answers :-)

Comment: Even if you *had* to compute the `n-1`th even number in order to compute the `n`th, you wouldn't use a list comprehension. You would just use a loop. There's no reason to keep a previous even number around once you have used it to compute the next one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
def nth_even(n):
    return (n - 1) * 2
```

Comment: Removing the comprehension is a fantastic answer - well done!

Answer (score 4):

If you start from 0, and look for the n_th even number. Then just do the following:

```py
def nth_even(n):
   return (n-1)*2
```

Comment: Removing the comprehension is a fantastic answer - well done!